# How to update symbology without loading all symbols into TOC using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, labeling, symbology, color-ramp

I am using ArcMap 10.0  Service pack 5.
(government computer, no choice here). I am trying to automate a common mapping task...

I have a clipped layer (SoilsClipped - which has maybe 4 or 5 categories), and a layer with the symbology I want to use (SoilsSymbology - approximately 100 categories).

My goal is to get the clipped layer (SoilsClipped) to display in 50% transparent, Unique Values/many fields Color ramp, and a certain style of label. So I use:

```
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer()
```

With "False" for the symbology only parameter. (this seems to be the only way to get the 50% transparent and labels that I want)

This then resets the data source... so I reset it. But now I have ALL the symbols from the SoilsSymbology layer in the TOC, most of which aren't used in my SoilsClipped layer.

Is there a workaround for this? It looks like I would have access to other properties in 10.1 and upward that would make this method obsolete, but I can't figure out how to do this in 10.0.

Here is the code I am using right now...

```
cLeft,cRight = lyrSoils.dataSource.rsplit("\\",1)
cRight = str(lyrSoils.datasetName)

# set display properties
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(dfPlanView,lyrSoils,lyrSoilAttributeSource,False)

#arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyrSoils.name, lyrSoilAttributeSource)

# re-get layer pointer, it gets messed up with updatelayer
lyrSoils = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxdCurrent,"Soils Map")[0]

# fix data source
lyrSoils.replaceDataSource(cLeft,"SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE", cRight)
```

Answer (score 1):

Importing the symbology may do the trick or do you may need to take this through ArcPy.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002p000000